# Navigation Component: Get Activity Result

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the `NavController` to start an activity - which has its own navigation graph - for the login/register flow.
Now I would like to have the result of `LoginActivity`(success, failure) inside the `MainActiviy` to update the UI.

```
MainActvity (start)-> LoginActivity
MainActvity <-(result) LoginActivity end
```

Is it possible to handle this situation with navigation component or do I have to use something like `startActivityForResult(LoginActivity...)` to get 
the result from the `LoginActivity`?

Or is there a better way? I think a possible solution could be using the same instance of a viewModel between Activities but not really sure if this is possible. :-/

Answer (score 1):

it's possible with:

If Fragment A needs a result from Fragment B..

A should get the savedStateHandle from the currentBackStackEntry, call getLiveData providing a key and observe the result.

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Type>("key")?.observe(
    viewLifecycleOwner) {result ->
    // Do something with the result.
}
```

B should get the savedStateHandle from the previousBackStackEntry, and set the result with the same key as the LiveData in A

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
```

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220#comment55